# What is meant by "Touch" in Vimeo Javascript API

Tags: javascript, api, vimeo, froogaloop

I would like to ask what is meant by "Touch" as opposed to "Mobile" in Vimeo JS API [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjwEd.jpg). Does "Touch" include Android tablets / iPads or not?

Thanks for answers,
Joe

Comment: It's about touch screen devices (phones, tablets, notebooks).

Comment: So OK, but then what is "mobile" there [link](http://imgur.com/nBRpO6Z)? I'm not sure but mostly touch devices are also mobile. So there are two columns for the same thing but they has different features for API???

Answer (score 0):

"Touch" is the equivalent for "click" in the devices with touch screens

Comment: So OK, but then what is "mobile" there [link](http://imgur.com/nBRpO6Z)? I'm not sure but mostly touch devices are also mobile. So there are two columns for the same thing but they has different features for API???